# Prove the inequality by mean value theorem of integral calculus: $1/3\sqrt2\leq\int_0^1 x^2/\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq1/3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> $$\frac{1}{3\sqrt2}\leq\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\leq\frac{1}{3}$$

I took $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, but then $g(x)$ isn't continuous in $[0,1]$.

What functions to choose?

Comment: That's an odd one,  normally you'd calculate the secant line of the integrand over the bounds of the integral for the mean value theorem,  but that's an improper integral since the integrand isn't defined at 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct.

According to Wolfy,
$\int_0^1 x^2dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}
=\frac{\pi}{4}
\approx .7854
$.

An easy lower bound
can be gotten from
$(1-x)^{-1/2}
\ge 1+\frac{x}{2}
$
so that
$(1-x^2)^{-1/2}
\ge 1+\frac{x^2}{2}
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1 x^2dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}
&\ge \int_0^1 x^2(1+\frac{x^2}{2})dx\\
&\ge \int_0^1 (x^2+\frac{x^4}{2})dx\\
&=\frac13+\frac1{10}\\
&=\frac{13}{30}\\
&=0.43333...\
\end{array}
$

To do the evaluation,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2(t)\cos(t)dt}{\cos(t)}
\quad x=\sin(t), dx=\cos(t)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(t)dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{array}
$